# Flutter: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'

Tags: android, flutter

after running the debugging of a standard flutter application (after creation) through the bluestack emulator, I get the given error in the terminal:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G988N in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\Mariusz\Desktop\dart\firstproject\android\settings.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not load compiled classes for script 'C:\Users\Mariusz\Desktop\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' from cache.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

where is the error if I have not made any changes in the code

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by updating the flutter sdk

Comment: exact version number please